# How to integrate Alpine.js into a Rails 7 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, alpine.js, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulusjs

I have a Rails 7 application with Stimulus in it and I downloaded a TailwindCSS template that uses the AlpineJS framework. Apparently, the way I integrated Alpine.JS into the Rails app is not proper, because not JS-dynamic elements dont' work.

Here are the AlpineJS-related modifications I made in the Rails app to integrate it.

**app/javascript/application.js**:

```
// Configure your import map in config/importmap.rb. Read more: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
import Alpine from "alpinejs"
import "plugin"

window.Alpine = Alpine  
Alpine.start()
```

**config/importmap.rb**:

```
pin "application"
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js"
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js"
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/plugin", under: "plugin"
pin "alpinejs" # @3.10.2
```

**Gemfile**:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby "3.2.2"
gem "rails", "~> 7.1.3"
gem "sprockets-rails"
gem "pg", "~> 1.1"
gem "puma", ">= 5.0"
gem "importmap-rails"
gem "turbo-rails"
gem "stimulus-rails"
gem "jbuilder"
gem "redis", ">= 4.0.1"
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ windows jruby ]
gem "bootsnap", require: false
gem "rollbar"
gem "tailwindcss-rails"
gem "devise"
gem 'dotenv-rails', groups: [:development, :test]

group :development, :test do
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri windows ]
end

group :development do
  gem "web-console"
end

group :test do
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
end
```

**app/assets/config/manifest.js**:

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
//= link_tree ../../javascript .js
//= link_tree ../../../vendor/javascript .js
//= link_tree ../builds
```

When I load the Rails 7 app, there is `window.Alpine` output in the Chrome Console.
[image]
What configuration am I missing yet?

Comment: how does `import "plugin"` relate to alpine here? you're missing `plugin/index.js` file so you can't import "plugin".